# How to use pivot in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, azure-synapse

I have a table that looks like below:

[image]

Need to convert the same into the below format:

[image]

The data is at A,B, C level. Tried using case when as shown below but it is resulting in multiple rows. So thinking of using a pivot.

```
Select a,b,c,
       case when D = N and E = 1 then N1 = value,
       case when D = N and E = 2 then N2 = value,
       case when D = O and E = 1 then O1 = value,
       case when D = O and E = 2 then O2 = value,
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: N1 = MAX(CASE WHEN D = 'N' AND E = 1 THEN value END),
...
GROUP BY a,b,c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
Select a, b, c,
       max(case when D = 'N' and E = 1 then value end) as N1,
       max(case when D = 'N' and E = 2 then value end) as N2,
       max(case when D = 'O' and E = 1 then value end) as O1,
       max(case when D = 'O' and E = 2 then value end) as O2
from t
group by a, b, c;
```

Note that this also fixes the logic in the `case` expressions.